# searching for a string while looping

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I am trying to format another sites data to insert into my database. He wants to close his site, so is giving me his sites listings. But im having to format his data from his flatfile database, to go into my mysql database.

Im looping through his text file, and getting his values. Then formatting as needed before inserting them into my DB.

Because our sites use completely different storage formats and fields, im having a few problems with something.

My site has a designer field. His doesnt. so im trying to search through his description field to find a match within my designer table. If there is a match i want to get the designer ID to insert into the designer id field. But i cant get this code to work.

Could someone please suggest a fix? or if theres a better way to do this?

```
$fp = fopen('listings.txt','r');
if (!$fp) {echo 'ERROR: Unable to open file.'; exit;}

$loop = 0;

while (!feof($fp)) {
$loop++;
$line = fgets($fp,1024); //use 2048 if very long lines
$field[$loop] = explode ('  ', $line);


$get_designers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dress_designers");
$row_designers = mysql_fetch_array($get_designers);
$totalRows_designers = mysql_num_rows($get_designers);

do{
// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.

$mystring = strtolower($field[$loop][8]);
$findme   = strtolower($row_designers['designer_name']);
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
$designer = "Other";
} else {
$designer = "Siopa Rince";
}

} while ($row_designers = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_designers));

$fp++;
}

fclose($fp);
```

I only put "Siopa Rince" as a test. But this isnt working. If i take the text from the file, and paste it in the $mystring and put siopa rince in $findme... it works.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Danny

OK... what about just entering the info as is? I tried a few different ways, but the result is returning null...

After i insert the data, ill use searches to join the required row to get an ID:

```
SELECT dress_test.dress_title, (

SELECT dress_designers.designer_id
FROM dress_designers
WHERE MATCH (
dress_test.dress_desc
)
AGAINST (
'dress_designers.designer_name'
IN boolean MODE
)
) AS real_designer_id
FROM dress_test
```

Another version:

```
SELECT dress_test.dress_title, dress_designers.designer_name 
FROM dress_test
JOIN dress_designers ON MATCH(dress_test.dress_title, dress_test.dress_desc) AGAINST
('dress_designers.designer_name' in boolean mode)
```

Any other suggestions??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first assignment to `$row_designers` uses `mysql_fetch_array`, while your second uses `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Instead of do { ... } while, why not just while () { ... }

Remove this line `$row_designers = mysql_fetch_array($get_designers);`

And turn your loop into...

```
while ($row_designers = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_designers)) {
  // string search here
}
```

Everything else looks fine - if you're having troubles, check the values with either `echo` to print string or `print_r` to print arrays.